# problem in finding a common ancestor for two nodes

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have the following code for finding the  common ancestor of two nodes in a binary search tree.  If the code can find the nth common ancestor that common ancestor will be returned and if there is no common ancestor (-1) will be returned. Logically the code seems to be correct but there is an error in code development that I can not find that. Is there any body to help?

I have added the binary search tree image that is not displayed!!!

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the condition `commonParent->data != n`?

Comment: in order to find the nth common parent: e.g: first, 2nd etc...

Comment: What does `data` have to do with that?

Comment: I think this is a "trick" exercise where you're supposed to realize that you can infer the ancestrage from the given level-order array without building a tree.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I don't think that is true. It is not at all evident where a level ends in the input (the tree is not guaranteed to be a *complete* binary tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison and condition `commonParent->data != n` is comparing apples with oranges, i.e. *data* with a count. They are unrelated. You cannot expect `commonParent` to somehow walk `n-1` steps upwards with this. It is already too late for that -- `commonParent` is the node for when `n` is 1, but for other values of `n` you need to go *up* the tree.

I would suggest to first count the number of nodes that are common ancestors of `b` and `c`, then check if `n` is less than or equal to that, and if so, to traverse the tree again to find the corresponding node.

Code:

```
int countCommonAncestors(Node* root, int c, int b) {
    int count = 0;
    while (root != nullptr) {
        count++;
        if (root->data > c && root->data > b) {
            root = root->left;
        } else if (root->data < c && root->data < b) {
            root = root->right;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int getDataOnPath(Node* root, int b, int level) {
    while (level-- > 0) {
        root = root->data > b ? root->left : root->right;
    }
    return root->data;
}
```

In your `main` you can then do:

```
    int count = countCommonAncestors(root, c, b);
    int result = count < n ? -1 : getDataOnPath(root, b, count - n);
    cout << result << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer (and I believe it's better for this type of question), that will point you in the correct direction.

First of all, get rid of C-style raw pointers and arrays, change your Node structure to

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
    Node(int val) : data(val), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};
```

because your tree models unique ownership of the nodes. Then change your tree builder signature to:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> buildBST(std::vector<int> values) {
    if (values.empty()) return nullptr;
    auto root = std::make_unique<Node>(values.front());
    for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); ++i) {
        int val       = values[i];
        Node* current = root.get();
        while (true) {
/* etc etc ... the rest of your builder code */
}
```

Then, you are looking for nth parent of the 2 nodes, then provide desired ancestry level to your lookup function, preferably this way:

```
// or return Node* if you prefer
int findCommonParent(Node* root, int val1, int val2, int levelOfAncestry) {
/* body ... */
/* HINT: record the path while you are traversing the tree */
}
```

In the end, write unit tests for your code (googletest is very beginners friendly in this aspect):

```
TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    std::vector<int> values({25, 20, 36, 10, 22, 30, 40, 5, 12, 28, 38, 48});
    int valA = 5;
    int valB = 12;
    int expectedResult1 = 10;
    int expectedResult2 = 20;
    auto root = buildBST(values);
    ASSERT_EQ(expectedResult1, findCommonParent(root.get(), valA, valB, 1));
    ASSERT_EQ(expectedResult2, findCommonParent(root.get(), valA, valB, 2));
}
```

You will end up with a clear code, and everything will become easier.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions that solved the problem. I am a cppbeginer and your code style is very helpful for me.